# Can I stop browsers from collapsing whitespace across span boundaries?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to render some text using spans with borders to show groupings. But if one span ends in whitespace, then the browser ignores any whitespace *outside* the span as well, and the borders get mashed up against each other.

I can see that *usually* those spaces are visually adjacent, so I'm not sure it's *technically* a rendering bug, but in this case it feels like one since there's a border in between that makes the difference visible.

Regardless of whether it's a bug, is there an easy work-around to prevent this? I do normally want white-space to collapse and wrap as usual, so... I guess I *could* write code to collapse white-space myself and use `pre-wrap` but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Note that I *do* want to put the borders right next to each other sometimes, when there's not supposed to be a space between.

Here's a minimal example. Note how the first two spans are separated slightly, but since the second one ends with a space inside the span, the second and third are mashed together.

```
<style>span { padding: 1ex;  border: thin solid black; }</style>
<p><span>span</span> <span>span_ </span> <span>span</span></p>
```

I'm... a little lost as to where to even start looking on this one. I could put a non-breaking space between spans, but then that prevents it from wrapping there. I guess I could put the white space between spans and then follow it with a non-breaking space? Or... hmm. Replacing the final space inside the span with a non-breaking space also gives me the behavior I want.

But I'm really hoping there's some kind of styling setting that'll make the browser treat span breaks as substantial so I don't have to add another text processing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` tags are `inline` by default, so apparently the two whitespaces are "merged" into one by the browser.

But if you define them as `inline-block`s, the whitespace between them appears as desired:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1ex;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<p><span>span</span> <span>span_ </span> <span>span</span></p>
```

Comment: Gah, I should have thought to try that. Beautiful, thanks.